# How to get and display routes and directions in windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

i want to get the routes on map and direction in windows phone 8.1 app in c#.I am using this code but it show "invalid credentials"
please reply

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MapService.ServiceToken = "AgyhW8zBh1zs6Umd7H6CZwDUf7jc2YerR2t1dpxQzWLM3nPzZcR3d3jQNXXGg0xw";
    // Start at Microsoft in Redmond, Washington.
    BasicGeoposition startLocation = new BasicGeoposition();
    startLocation.Latitude = 47.643;
    startLocation.Longitude = -122.131;
    Geopoint startPoint = new Geopoint(startLocation);

    // End at the city of Seattle, Washington.
    BasicGeoposition endLocation = new BasicGeoposition();
    endLocation.Latitude = 47.604;
    endLocation.Longitude = -122.329;
    Geopoint endPoint = new Geopoint(endLocation);

    // Get the route between the points.
    MapRouteFinderResult routeResult =
        await MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync(
        startPoint,
        endPoint,
        MapRouteOptimization.Time,
        MapRouteRestrictions.None);

    if (routeResult.Status == MapRouteFinderStatus.Success)
    {
        // Display summary info about the route.
        tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new Run()
        {
            Text = "Total estimated time (minutes) = " + routeResult.Route.EstimatedDuration.TotalMinutes.ToString()
        });

        tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());

        tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new Run()
        {
            Text = "Total length (kilometers) = " + (routeResult.Route.LengthInMeters / 1000).ToString()
        });

        tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
        tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());

        // Display the directions.
        tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new Run()
        {
            Text = "DIRECTIONS"
        });

        tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());

        foreach (MapRouteLeg leg in routeResult.Route.Legs)
        {
            foreach (MapRouteManeuver maneuver in leg.Maneuvers)
            {
                tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new Run()
                {
                    Text = maneuver.InstructionText
                });

                tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
             }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        tbOutputText.Text = "A problem occurred: " + routeResult.Status.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Double check your Service Token. We can't help much for this "Invalid Credentials" case

Comment: after adding service token correctly it just showing textblock doesn't showing the route